# Querying A Specific 3D Point Using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012

Currently I am designing a method that takes a `List<LineSegment>` as input and outputs an altered list with the `LineSegment`s all following a clockwise direction.  The `LineSegment` class is essentially as follows:

```
public class LineSegment
{
    Point basePoint;
    Point endPoint;
{
```

with the `Point`s as simple 3D points.  My problem is that after I refactor a `LineSegment` into pointing in the right direction (with `basePoint` to `endPoint` being clockwise), I need to find the next line segment in the `List<LineSegment>`.  I understand the theory behind finding it (based on whether we switched around the base and end points, the next segment's base or end point will be one of those), but I am unsure as to how to query it using LINQ.  I did some research on using LINQ and came up with something like

```
LineSegment nextSegment = 
    listOfSegments.Any(p => p.basePoint.Equals(otherSegment.endPoint));
```

to return the LineSegment that matches the `otherSegment.endPoint` criteria, but only to find that .Any() returns a bool.

How can I return the LineSegment that I am searching for instead of a bool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx) like:

```
LineSegment nextSegment = 
    listOfSegments.FirstOrDefault(p => p.basePoint.Equals(otherSegment.endPoint));
```

But this will assume that your `Point` compares its values and not references.

If you want to compare Point's fields then you can do:

```
LineSegment nextSegment = 
    listOfSegments.FirstOrDefault(p => p.basePoint.X == otherSegment.endPoint.X &&
                                       p.basePoint.Y == otherSegment.endPoint.Y &&
                                       p.basePoint.Z == otherSegment.endPoint.Z ));
```

Comment: I have equality overridden in Point, so the first will work.  Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FirstOrDefault(Func<T, Boolean>)`.

***Returns the first element of the sequence that satisfies a condition or a default value if no such element is found.***

```
LineSegment nextSegment = 
    listOfSegments.FirstOrDefault(p => p.basePoint.Equals(otherSegment.endPoint));
```

Also, to check for value equality, you should generally use `Equals`. However, `Equals` as it is implemented by `Object` just performs a reference identity check. It is therefore important, when you call `Equals`, to verify whether the type overrides it to provide value equality semantics. When you create your own types, you should override `Equals`. So, I am suggesting to add these methods to your class, if you haven't:

```
public override bool Equals ( object obj )
{
   return Equals(obj as Point);
}

public bool Equals ( Point obj )
{
   return obj != null && obj.X == this.X && obj.Y == this.Y && obj.Z == this.Z; 
}
```

You can use `First` also. But, it will throw Exception if nothing found.

*Update1*:

If you're expecting a Single record, you can use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do exact same thing 2 weeks ago for drawing my 3D object and linking them. But as other state using `FirstOrDefault` is not good if you have the same case as me where 1 vertices have multiple end point like a cube can as example the matching set for (0,0,0) i have 3 lines :

```
(start) - ( end  )
(0,0,0) - (15,0,0)
(0,0,0) - (0,92,0)
(0,0,0) - (0,0,32)
```

I personally had to go with the `Where` which output the whole matching list

```
public class LineSeg
{
    Point startPoint;
    Point endPoint;
{

// vertexOfOrigin is a Point object

// get every line where the point given is the starting point
var fromVertexes = lstLineSeg.Where(line => line.endPoint == vertexOfOrigin).ToList();

// get every line where the point given is the end point
var toVertexes = lstLineSeg.Where(line => line.startPoint == vertexOfOrigin).ToList();
```